# Plain XeTeX Edmac facing pages

Tags: edmac

A possibly vain hope, but here goes.  I use Edmac to typeset Early English texts for (unsurprisingly) the Early English Text Society.  They have in prospect a companion volume to the sample here:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8q1rre1dyk4n641eghe5j/Sample-Scan.pdf?rlkey=ksx7v4qs8wgm69yl754i82p0n&dl=1

[image]

which was published some years ago, I think using Arboritext, by a retired typesetter. For this job there is the edition itself on the left-hand page, and a parallel related manuscript on the right, which has to keep in tandem.  I have done facing-page prose editions for the British Academy - a nuisance in TeX as manual intervention is required to force page breaks - but it's doable.  However, you will see from the sample that the apparatus is extremely heavy and therefore has to be split between left and right pages to create an aesthetically acceptable result (otherwise we would often have just a few lines of main text on the left, a large apparatus beneath, and a largely blank right-hand page with just a few lines to keep in step with the left-hand text).  I have a few Heath Robinson-type ideas (an initial pass with the apparatus at half size then a lot of fiddly work which I won't go into here).  Is there any elegant solution to this that people can think of?  What is wanted is a pass that puts all the (half-size) apparatus in a box, splits the box into two, and saves the bottom half for output on the facing page at a second pass, which would have the apparatus full size on both sides of the page spread.  I suspect impossible in TeX, but I've seen contributors achieve the impossible before!  John  (PS - is there some easy way to embed a PDF in these messages?)

Comment: you can't embed a pdf but you can upload a screenshot. Is there any special requirement to restrict yourself to plain tex, you may find more features in latex eg reledmac package

Comment: your image shows (I think) reduced size apparatus split over the spread, but your suggested  algorithm if I read it right says you want the apparatus to end up at the body font size?

Comment: please edit this question, the link is broken.